# Vim vundle colorschemes - vimrc

Tags: vim

Hi I have been trying to configure vim on ubuntu.

All the packages seem to install fine. However if installing a colorscheme via vundle and then using colorscheme name it doesn't appear to find the scheme.

I have attempted to install railscasts, solarized and desert-warm but all have failed to load.

This is my .vimrc am I doing something wrong?

```
set nocompatible               " be iMproved
filetype off                   " required!

colorscheme desert-warm 

" next tab
map <F7> :tabn    
" previous tab
map <F8> :tabp
" Close Tab abd save
map <F9> ZZ
" open and edit file
map <F6> :tabedit

set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/vundle/
call vundle#rc()

" let Vundle manage Vundle
" required!
Bundle 'gmarik/vundle'

" My Bundles here:
"
" original repos on github
Bundle 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Bundle 'Lokaltog/vim-easymotion'
Bundle 'rstacruz/sparkup', {'rtp': 'vim/'}
Bundle 'tpope/vim-rails.git'
Bundle 'desert-warm-256'
" vim-scripts repos

Bundle 'L9'
Bundle 'FuzzyFinder'
" non github repos
Bundle 'git://git.wincent.com/command-t.git'
Bundle 'https://github.com/vim-scripts/perl-support.vim.git'
Bundle 'https://github.com/Raimondi/delimitMate.git'
Bundle 'https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized.git'
Bundle 'https://github.com/jpo/vim-railscasts-theme.git'
" ...

filetype plugin indent on     " required!
"
" Brief help
" :BundleList          - list configured bundles
" :BundleInstall(!)    - install(update) bundles
" :BundleSearch(!) foo - search(or refresh cache first) for foo
" :BundleClean(!)      - confirm(or auto-approve) removal of unused bundles
"
" see :h vundle for more details or wiki for FAQ
" NOTE: comments after Bundle command are not allowed..
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try moving the `colorscheme` call to the end of the file.

Also, the color scheme name from your example doesn't work for me—it should be `colorscheme desert-warm-256`. To see a list of color schemes currently installed, try entering `:colorscheme <TAB>` interactively.

Answer (score 6):

I think the answer to this question is that there is no `call vundle#end()` or `syntax on`  in the original poster's .vimrc.

Adding these two lines and for example the `colorscheme solarized` line anywhere after the `call vundle#end()` would have solved the issue.

Comment: Thanks, put color scheme line after vundle#() solved my problem

Comment: I believe an earlier version of vundle did not require this call to `vundle#end()`. I had to add this when doing a git clone of vundle on a new machine. See example .vimrc [link](https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim#quick-start)

Answer (score 1):

`colorscheme desert-warm` must come after `Bundle 'desert-warm-256'` since it is the Bundle command that adds things to the path:

```
Bundle 'desert-warm-256'
colorscheme desert-warm
```

Source: [same question on GitHub issue](https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim/issues/119).

Note: Vundle has recently (2014-03-18) swapped to using `Plugin` instead of `Bundle`, so after you `git pull` it will be:

```
Plugin 'desert-warm-256'
colorscheme desert-warm
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write your "colorsheme desert bla bla" line AFTER the Plugin line. Because Vundle first needs to install this color plugin, and after than it can use it. Sorry my tiresome English.